# PHP - print multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a brain-block with this piece of code. I want to print a multidimensional array in PHP where the 'columns' are separated by hyphens and the 'rows' are separated by newlines.

My problem is that my code prints a '-' at the end of each row. This is obvious when looking at my code:

*N.B. (`$result` is a 2D array i.e. `$result[][]`)*

```
foreach($result as $row){
    foreach($row as $column){
            echo $column . "-";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

This is the output:

```
42-1-1394752507-16.125-
43-1-1394752569-16.125-
44-1-1394752632-16.562-
45-1-1394752693-17.125-
```

What is the best way to print this out to avoid the trailing `-` on each row? I could do a check to see if the current `$column` is the last element in the `$row` but I don't actually know how to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`implode` is your friend:

```
foreach($result as $row){
    echo implode('-', $row) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and is even simpler than what I thought I needed to do. Thanks! Will accept in 5 mins when it lets me

Comment: @exantas: I always look for a built-in function, especially to not loop :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the inner foreach you could just use [implode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
implode($row,"-");
```

Comment: You don't want to implode the `$column` it's not an array.  And your args are backwards.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: For "historical reasons", you *can* swap the order of parameters.  From the docs: `implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less confusing to use the documented order of arguments.`  http://php.net/implode

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Doh, its been so long since I looked at the `implode` manual, but that memory smacks me in the head now.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Of course you are right. I edited my answer according the first parameter. PHP.net also states that this order of the arguments should not be used

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$row = [
    '42' => [1, 2, 3],
    '43' => [2, 3, 4],
];

array_walk($row, function($item, $key) {
    echo $key . implode('-', $item) . PHP_EOL;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could do a check to see if the current $column is the last element
>   in the $row but I don't actually know how to do this

`implode()` is the way to go, but if you want to understand how to find out if the current column is the last one:

```
// foreach (value)
foreach($result as $row){
  $column_count = count($row);

  // for each (key => value)
  foreach($row as $column_index => $column){
    echo $column;

    if($column_index < $column_count - 1){
      echo "-";
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: I liked this answer as well. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

one option:

```
foreach($result as $row){
$c='';
    foreach($row as $column){
            $c.= $column . "-";
    }
    $c=rtrim($c,'-');
    echo "$c\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you also want to avoid a trailing newline, you could use this one-liner:

```
echo implode(array_map(function($row) {return implode('-', $row);}, $result), "\n");
```

of course, oneliners are ugly and not clean code.

what does this code do? it uses `implode` on each row, and `array_map` creates a flat (1-dimensional) array of already imploded rows. that is again imploded with newline.

finally, this solution is not the most performant one. but it's a neat oneliner :)

Comment: that is not a one liner. the rules say that a one-liner cannot exceed 3 function calls